# Finding zoning GIS maps/shapefiles of US online

Tags: geospatial, usa

I need the classification of residential, commercial and mixed areas of cities in the US as defined by mayor councils. Where can I find the zoning GIS maps/ shapefiles online?

Answer (score 1):

You can Find the information city wise here:
http://us-city.census.okfn.org/dataset/zoning

This is free data and can be downloaded in bulk as well.
One of the sample of zoning is as provided [here](https://data.austintexas.gov/Locations-and-Maps/City-Of-Austin-Properties-handled-by-the-Office-of/3msr-mkgq)

If you have a budget as well then you can get the complete data on arcgis.
Sample of the same in action can be viewed [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?useExisting=1&layers=49ad06a6b8c945debbbea865b1832ee2)

Bonus: You can have other detailed datasets like *Demographic Statistics By Zip Code* [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset)